# non-linear correlation or finding thresholds for changes with relatively few data points

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, nonlinear-regression, threshold

I'm a novice at stats and thought I'd ask this question to those with much more experience than me.

I've got temperature data and count data for number of animals hibernating in man-made boxes. The temperature data is very detailed (hourly) but there are relatively few counts (12 in total split between four sites) that fall within the recorded temperature range. Each of the four sites has 15 counts throughout the year but only 3 of them are within the winter period that we measured temperature for.

The hypothesis we are working with is that the animals use the boxes more when temps are colder (i.e. generally within the winter months) but that at a certain temperature (to be determined) the boxes are not thermally stable enough and the animals move underground. This is currently only an observational trend.

My question is in two parts:
How can I go about looking for the lower threshold where the animals abandon the boxes and how can I tell whether this is a significant change.

Currently what I've done is made some variables from the temperature data to provide the minimum temperature for the previous week and the average temp the previous week for each count date. I've also transformed the counts into proportions to attempt to control for the effect of the differing sites so the "count" element is now a proportion of the highest count recorded in that site.

I thought about completing a blocked ANOVA where my block is site and then the groups being the counts split above and below a certain temperature. E.G. count when the temperature drops below 0oC and count when the temp was above 0oC and just putting it in a loop with possible values (maybe in increments of 0.5oC) but that doesn't seem very efficient and I'm wondering if I would lose information/oversimplify things.

The other thing I considered was a non-linear correlation test that I saw on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695991/finding-non-linear-correlations-in-r) on stack overflow. I'm cautious of just choosing a test just because its what I found first if there might be a more robust option. I'm working in R if that makes a difference.

The other option available (though I'd like to avoid if possible because I'm doing this as volunteering for a charity) is purchasing temp data online which would put all points (60 total) and mean that there were two winter seasons to compare.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or if you think one of the approaches I considered above would work.

Comment: To be quite honest, with just 12 data points (spread across four sites, which may also have an effect and which you may therefore also need to model), you will not be able to obtain reliable results for any kind of effect, whether linear, threshold or nonlinear. Sorry, I understand that this is not what you are looking for. You will need to collect more data. (I recommend conducting a power analysis and sample size calculation before collecting data, precisely to avoid this kind of issue.)

Comment: Hi @StephanKolassa thanks for your comment. I was not involved with any of the data collection unfortunately so the small sample size is a limitation I can't do much about. I can however look into purchasing additional temperature data  so that the other points collected could be added to the analysis as mentioned above. How would you go about analysing that? Even if not enough to produce statistically significant results, we hoped it would be enough of a pilot study to   show either support or not (as the case may be) for the observation and determine if another years data would be useful?

Comment: I understand your predicament, this kind of thing happens far too often. Do I understand correctly that you have observed counts for other time points and may be able to obtain the corresponding temperature data? It may be possible to use the data you have as a pilot study to determine the kind of sample size necessary for your analysis. Can you edit your post to include the data you do have?

Comment: Yet another example of the great quote from Ronald Fisher: "To call in the statistician after the experiment is done may be no more than asking him to perform a post-mortem examination: he may be able to say what the experiment died of".